# iPhone UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, orientation, uinavigationbar

I'm using UINavigationController and I have a UIView added to self.window

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView.frame=CGRectMake(0,20,320,100);//20 is to position view under status bar
[[[self.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myView];
```

This is done in AppDelegate.m file.

And this way myView covers up the navigation bar completely.

However, when the screen orientation changes, somehow the navigation bar is brought to the very front (just like what bringSubViewToFront does) and is on top of myView (a portion of view is covered up by navigation bar).

Does anyone know why this happened? Is there a way I can keep myView on top of everything?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show the navigation bar, just hide it:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

or:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

if you want to animate the change from not hidden to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the "z" coordinate for stuff on the screen

```
[aview sendSubviewToBack:asubview];
```

and

```
[aview sendSubviewToFront:asubview];
```